# Evince fails to open

Tags: 18.04, evince

Since re-installing 18.04, evince document reader is failing to open. The files can be opened with other readers. I have removed and reinstalled evince.

The symptoms are:Whether I double click a pdf or call evince from the applications window, the wheel of hesitation appears for a few seconds and then all goes quiet. If I run in terminal, I get the message 'segmentation error, core dumped.' In /var/crash, I have several dumps, mostly of 0 bytes, although there is one significant one. I don't know how to make sense of it, and I don't think I can attach it here.

Anyone else seeing this, or any suggestions?

Comment: Use `ubuntu-bug /var/crash/[name.of.crash.file].crash` to report the issue you have.  Once submitted, you can provide the launchpad ID here and we can view the detail/issue you have...

Comment: But I can't see how to make an attachment. Does that require a level of 'reputation'?

Comment: Sorry I should have provided https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs as a link.   If you search for the word 'attachment' it should help explain how you upload attachments (they are added via a browser; instead of the `ubuntu-bug` first step which uploads from your machine directly; though that step will likely open a browser to get you to login, then answer questions etc. which will allow adding attachments.

Comment: OK, thanks, guiverc. I think I have now reported the problem via the Ubuntu error tracker. Feeling very thick, but I couldn't find my way through launchpad. The tracker  link is https://errors.ubuntu.com/oops/34f5d73e-f27d-11e9-b5dd-fa163e102db1